# Match everything after particular pattern except whitespace till next letter

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
'Medicine Treatment:     Not applicable'
```

Now, I want to match the according treatment but without the white spaces infront of the treatment. 
So I just want to match: `"Not applicable"`
and not `"      Not applicable"`

Im pretty sure it must be something like this:

```
(?<=Medicine Treatment:)[^\s].*
```

or `(?<=Medicine Treatment:)\S.*`

... `(?<=Medicine Treatment:).*`  returns only what I do not want: `"      Not applicable"`

Comment: Use a capture group, `Medicine Treatment:\s*(.*)`

Comment: Thats perfect, could you explain why I dont have to ´Medicine Treatment´ within brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `re` does not support patterns matching strings of unknown length (though it is possible with [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)). So, you can't use `re.search(r'(?<=Medicine Treatment:\s*).*', txt)` (it would work with PyPi `regex.search`).

You may use a capturing group instead of a lookbehind:

```
import re
s = 'Medicine Treatment:     Not applicable'
m = re.search(r'Medicine Treatment:\s*(.*)', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => Not applicable
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tdth5f)

**Details**

- `Medicine Treatment:` - a literal string (serves as left-hand context of the required match)
- `\s*` - consumes zero or more whitespace chars
- `(.*)` - captures into Group 1 any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possble.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using regex but by combining the `split()` and `strip()` functions :

```
s = 'Medicine Treatment:     Not applicable'
s.split('Medicine Treatment:')[1].strip()
```

Output :

```
'Not applicable'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string `s`, `s.strip()` will be a copy of the string without whitespace on the sides, and `s.lstrip()` will only remove whitespace from the left.